# SpriteKit - How can I catch the event when the touch moves over a sprite, but didn't actually begin on the sprite

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, touch, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

In SpriteKit, I want to catch event when touch moves over a sprite, but hasn't actually started on this sprite, but on another piece of SKScene.

I can catch touchesBegan inside the SKSpriteNode A if the touch starts on it and then dragged over it, but not when touch started on another node - B - and then dragged over my node - A. Anyone knows how to catch this one, because I think I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Christian W. but I have a simpleer solution for now, although it is not what I had on mind actually:
Just put this in Scene and catch the touchesMoved inside it, having this code inside it:

```
SKNode * draggedOverNode = [self nodeAtPoint:location];
[draggedOverNode touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
```

And implement the touchesMoved function inside that object that actually extends the SKNode (which most of your classes will do).

Answer (score 1):

try this: 
sorry this is swift.. but you can easily do the same thing in obj c

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))
    var startedOutsideSprite = true

    override init(size: CGSize) {
        super.init(size: size)
        sprite.position = CGPointMake(size.width/2, size.height/2)
        addChild(sprite)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
            if !sprite.containsPoint(location) {
                startedOutsideSprite = true
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

            if sprite.containsPoint(location) && startedOutsideSprite {
                print("yayyy")
                // your code here
            }
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        startedOutsideSprite = false
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```